# Filter c# object with JObject

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, json.net

Let me preface by saying I'm very new to C# development so if the solution seems obvious I apologize.

I'm getting a JSON string back from a user and I need to filter a list of C# objects based on what the JSON string contains. The JSON can only have fields that my C# model has but I don't know what fields the JSON string will contain. My C# model looks something like this:

```cs
public class Enrollment {
  public int Year { get; set; }
  public int NumEnrolls { get; set; }
  public int DaysIntoEnrollment { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The JSON will have one or more of these properties with values to filter out. It could look like this:

```js
{
    "Year": ["2020", "2019"],
    "Name": ["CourseA", "CourseB"],
    "DaysIntoEnrollment": "20"
}
```

I need to filter my list of Enrollment objects based on the above JSON. So I would want the end result to have all Enrollment objects that don't contain a Year of 2020 or 2019 for example.

I've gotten a filter to work with linq on a single property but my real model has much more properties that can be filtered and I'm looking for a compact solution that will work regardless of which properties are included in the JSON. This is what I have working

```cs
public void GetFilteredData(string filters) {

  var enrollList = new List<Enrollments>();  // Pretend this contains a list of valid Enrollment data
  var json = JObject.Parse(filters);  // filters string is in the json format from above
  
  var propsToFilter = 
    from p in json["Year"]
    select p;
  
  var filtered = enrollList.Where(e => !propsToFilter.Contains(e.Year.ToString())));
}
```

Is there a simple way to do this without manually going through each property like I did above?

Comment: When you mention "without manually going through each property", do you mean selecting the years (i.e. `var proposToFilter = ..`) or filtering the enrollment (i.e. `var filtered = ....`)?

Comment: Newtonsoft JSON.NET can do this automatically using reflections. Some object has some method like Parse<T> where T is the output type.

Comment: @IvanVargas I meant with `var filtered` because the properties that I need to filter by are in the JSON string. From what @Flutterish said, I think reflection is the answer so I'll look more into that. Thank you